# Javascript CSS Animation Library firmin vs emile

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm comparing 2 JS css animation libraries:

https://github.com/madrobby/emile

http://extralogical.net/projects/firmin/

Can somebody give some pros vs cons please? Or the differences in philosophy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decided on this:

https://github.com/visionmedia/move.js

Based purely on the reputation of visionmedia.